# What is the value of a variable not set explicitly?

Tags: mysql, database, null

If I declare a variable and then do not set it explicitly to null then would it be null automatically?  In other words, will the code below return true or false?

```
DECLARE @val CHAR(4)
If @val =  NULL
```

Comment: something makes me confused see this link I have found the above code from that :(http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/understandingthedifferencebetweenisnull/871/

Answer (score 1):

Neither.  Comparing anything to NULL gives NULL.